# Photos library on Catalina does not allow HEIC/Live Photo imports

Tags: catalina, photos.app, import, heic

Due to storage limitations we outsourced my mothers photo library to an external hard drive. This was still on her MacBook Air Early 2015 running on High Sierra. Later, we updated her machine to Catalina. Now we are facing a problem with Live Photos. All photos taken in live mode that were already in the library before updating to Catalina are JPEGs. But unfortunately, the library can not import any HEIC data and justifies this with the attempt of importing an unknown file format. I remember using HEIC on Catalina. Does anyone have an idea about possible causes of the problem?

EDIT: I found out that the library actually contains some HEIC pictures. However, previously shared and identical photos that have the live mode in my library do not have live mode in hers.